# Heading Rotor not reading invisible headings

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, rotor

Am using `CollectionView` to display content and inside CollectionViewCell I configured `Label` property `accessibilityTraits` as `header`.

When am trying to read headings through Rotor after enabling VoiceOver so it's only reading headings which are visible on screen but headings which are not visible Rotor just say heading not found. This looks Rotor can't recognise the invisible cells that's why it's keep saying heading not found.

Any help would be appreciated.